# Is there any reason why I should NOT use window.postMessage API for modern browsers, post 2016?

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

A lot of the content I find in regards to window.postMessage and iframe, cross-domain iframe communication seem dated.

For modern browsers >= IE9 .. it seems like vanilla js window.postMessage would suffice. Versus using a bigger package like easyXDM or others.

http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its mostly a security issue:

> Any window (including, for example, http://evil.example.com) can send a message to any other window, and you have no guarantees that an unknown sender will not send malicious messages. Having verified identity, however, you still should always verify the syntax of the received message. Otherwise, a security hole in the site you trusted to send only trusted messages could then open a cross-site scripting hole in your site.

Next, if you send using postMessage you open yourself up to that data being intercepted by a malicious site:

> A malicious site can change the location of the window without your knowledge, and therefore it can intercept the data sent using postMessage.

Furthermore, the transfer parameter, while optional, is not standard across all browsers:

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```

[Link to MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: The security issues you point out arise when you don't use the API properly - failing or ignoring to verify the sender, or not specifying a target of instance. If used correctly it's safe, as mentioned in the article.

Comment: Agree 100% - keyword 'if'